# 'changed' field in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have created the custom entity and on the form I am trying to display the 'changed' time of the entity.

I am using this code

```
$fields['changed'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')
        ->setLabel(t('Changed'))
        ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was last edited.'))
        ->setSetting('value', \date_iso8601($entity->changed->value))
        ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
          'label' => 'above',
          'weight' => 11,
        ])
        ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
          'weight' => 11,
        ])
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

But anyway the 'changed' timestamp isn't appearing, could you please help me ?

Comment: Try to remove the "setSetting()" method.

Comment: Have deleted both. But nothing changed. The interesting moment is that it works totally ok with the standard 'created' field. But the 'changed' one is not displayed.

Comment: Try it use only setLabel and setDesc, it should work. That's the way I use it too. And then gradually add your desired options. I could imagine that it doesn't work to show the "changed" field in the form, cause it doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: But for my task I need this field to be displayed. I guess, I just need a field formatter for this

Comment: Are sure you need it in the form? If you want to display it in the view, that's perfectly fine, but in the form?? You wouldn't really change the "changed" date by hand, would you?

Comment: No, i am not going to change it by hand. I just need to display it as a label.

Comment: @badm Can you tell us exactly what you're planning to do with it? Are you just going to display it as a label when you edit/update the form?

Comment: I tried it your way and it works for me... stupid question but maybe you forgot to clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, i need it to be displayed in the Edit form. No, I didn't forget to clear the cache

Comment: Ok now I fully understand what you want. Drupal automatically disables the changed field, as soon as you enable it in the form display. I guess what you CAN do is write a form hook and then just display the value of the changed property somewhere on the form page.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for my entity. This should work.

```
$fields['changed'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')
      ->setLabel(t('Changed'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was last edited.'));
```

Comment: Yep, this code is created automatically when you create a content entity. But is that field displayed on the page?

Comment: It's not displayed on the creation form because it is filled in automatically :P

Comment: I need it in the edit form, to display the time of the entity being changed in the past

Comment: If that's the case you should be able to get the entity you're looking for with the EntityTypeManager and insert the value of the created field :)

Comment: Sounds like a plan ;)